# Resize CGSize to the maximum with keeping the aspect-ratio

Tags: objective-c, c, swift, algorithm, cocoa-touch

I have a `CGSize` objects that  I need to send to my server. The maximum size I can send to the server is 900*900 (900 width/900 height).

There are some objects that are larger the 900*900 and I want to write a function that resizes them to the maximum (as I already say, the maximum is 900*900) but to keep the aspect ratio.

For example: if I have an object that is 1,000px width and 1,000px height I want the function to return a 900*900 object. If I have an object that is 1920px width and 1080px height I want it to return the maximum size possible with keeping the ratio.

Anyone have any idea how can I do that?

Thank you!

**OriginalUser2 answer:**

I've tried this code:

```
let aspect = CGSizeMake(900, 900)
let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1920, 1080)

let final = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(aspect, rect)
```

`final` is `{x 420 y 0 w 1,080 h 1,080}`, I can't understand why the `x = 420`, but anyway `1080*1080` is not in the same aspect ratio as `1920*1080` and it's bigger than `900*900`.

Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Take a look at [`AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect)

Comment: @originaluser2 I don't need it to fit in a `CGRect`, just to get the maximum size

Comment: Sure, so pass in `CGPointZero` for the origin, and just get out the size

Comment: @originaluser2 Hey thank you, I've edited my question with an answer for you answer, please take a look, thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `AVMakeRect(aspectRatio:insideRect:)` function from the AVFounation framework in order to do this.

The problem with your code is that the values are round the wrong way. The `insideRect:` parameter should be the rect to fit your size within, and the `aspectRatio:` should be the original size that you want to be scaled while maintaining aspect ratio.

For example:

```
import AVFoundation

// Original size which you want to preserve the aspect ratio of.
let aspect = CGSize(width: 1920, height: 1080)

// Rect to fit that size within. In this case you don't care about fitting
// inside a rect, so pass (0, 0) for the origin.
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 900, height: 900)

// Aspect fitted size, in this case (900.0, 506.25)
let result = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: aspect, insideRect: rect).size
```

Comment: change to *import AVKit - this is awesome

Comment: @n13 I don't see `AVMakeRect(aspectRatio:insideRect:)` in the [AVKit docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avkit) – only as part of [AVFoundation's functions](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/2009810-avfoundation_functions).

Comment: ^ You're right. I used import AVKit because AVFoundation appeared with a strikeout as if it was deprecated (which it isn't, just checked). Removed AVKit and it still works. XCode 8 / Swift 3.

Answer (score 3):

This code can be greatly reduced and modified, but for clarity's sake:

```
if myImage.width == myImage.height {
    // New image will be 900px by 900px
    newImage.width = (900 / myImage.width) * myImage.width
    newImage.height = (900 / myImage.height) * myImage.height
} else if myImage.width > myImage.height {
    // New image will have width of 900px
    newImage.width = (900 / myImage.width) * myImage.width
    newImage.height = (900 / myImage.width) * myImage.height
} else {
    // New Image will have height of 900px
    newImage.width = (900 / myImage.height) * myImage.width
    newImage.height = (900 / myImage.height) * myImage.height
}
```

In this snippet, `900` is the maximum width and height of the resized image, but this value can be abstracted with a variable for any value you would like.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have the image size, I'm passing `PHImageManagerMaximumSize`, so I need to fetch the full image first and then get the needed size for it and fetch again?

Comment: First of all, you need to state that in your question. Secondly, I'm not sure what you mean; couldn't you use this code after initially fetching the image?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I mean that I use `fetchImage(asset: size:)` so I need to provide the size in advanced. In the method you wrote on your comment I need to know the full size of the image. So do I need to fetch the full size image, them to call your method and get a new `CGSize` and then to fetch the image again with the new size?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `PHImageManager` class. If there is a way to retrieve the image's dimensions without fetching the entire image (like `getImageSize(asset: )` or something), then you should use that. If not, you will have to do it the way you said.