# Swift -how to make a smaller version of a 16:9 video thumbnail but keep the aspect ratio the same

Tags: ios, swift, cgsize

The aspect ratio for a 1080p hd video is 16:9 and to set a frame for the video in a cell so that it would fill it up completely I would use  `view.frame.width * 9 / 16`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    // the collection view is pinned to both sides of the vc with no spacing
    let width = collectionView.frame.width

    let videoHeight: CGFloat = width * 9 / 16

    return CGSize(width: width, height: videoHeight)
}

// inside the cell itself:

let videoHeight: CGFloat = self.frame.width * 9 / 16

contentView.addSubview(thumbnailImageView)
thumbnailImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
thumbnailImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
thumbnailImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

// here is where I set the thumbnail's height
thumbnailImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: videoHeight).isActive = true
```

This perfectly gives me:

[image]

The thing is I want a smaller version of the thumbnailImageView similar to youtube. I want to add the smaller thumbnailImageView on the left side of the screen but **keep the aspect ratio the same**.

[image]

The problem is when I attempted to do so I got a square instead of a rectangle. I divided the width of the cell by 3 and then multiplied it by 9 /16 but that isn't working. I used `(width / 3)` because I though it would keep the aspect ratio the same but reduce the size of the thumbnailImageView but it didn't work.

[image]

**Where am I going wrong at?**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    // the collection view is pinned to both sides of the vc with no spacing
    let width = collectionView.frame.width

    let videoHeight: CGFloat = (width / 3) * 9 / 16

    return CGSize(width: width, height: videoHeight)
}

// inside the cell itself
let videoHeight = (self.frame.width / 3) * 9 / 16

contentView.addSubview(thumbnailImageView)
thumbnailImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
thumbnailImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true

// here is where I set the thumbnail's height and width
thumbnailImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: videoHeight).isActive = true
thumbnailImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: videoHeight).isActive = true
```

Comment: The problem is the arithmetic. To scale a rectangle while keeping its aspect ratio, you must multiply (or divide) its height and width by _the same number_.

Comment: @matt what number should I divide it by?

Comment: Any number you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use AVMakeRect(aspectRatio:insideRect:) function to get a scaled rectangle that maintains the specified aspect ratio within a bounding rectangle.

You can refer the API [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/1390116-avmakerect).

By using the above API, your videoHeight value would be populated like below.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // the collection view is pinned to both sides of the vc with no spacing
    let width = collectionView.frame.width
    let rect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: CGSize(width: 16, height: 9), insideRect: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: width / 3, height: CGFloat.infinity)))
    let videoHeight: CGFloat = rect.size.height
    return CGSize(width: width, height: videoHeight)
}
```

And in cell, you can simply have height as follows.

```
let videoHeight = self.frame.height
```

Comment: I never used that function before, Im trying it now based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37996898/4833705. Gimme a couple of minutes

Comment: It's still coming out as a square but @matt in the comments said the issue is the math equation that I'm using. Let me get that part figured out first then I'll add it to the method that you posted.

Comment: Can you check the same with the snippet provided in the updated answer? And also do remove your videoHeight definition inside your function.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong. I added the code snippet you posted to both the cell using self.frame.width and inside sizeForItem I used collectionView.frame.width (the cv is pinned to both sides of the vc). If I don't use the videoHeight then I won't be able to set the cell's height. When I added it I still got a square

Comment: Inside sizeForItem it should be collectionView.frame.width / 3. And can you log your frame and height obtained?

Comment: My fault. I meant I added your code and inside sizeForItem I used *collectionView.frame.width / 3* and inside the cell I used *self.frame.width / 3*

Comment: Check my updated answer and let me know if you did the same.

Comment: I originally had the same code in sizeForItem from your original answer and also inside the cell (using self.frame.width / 3). Now I just c+p your updated code inside sizeForItem and inside the cell I set only the thumbnail's width: **let videoHeight = self.frame.height; thumbnailImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: videoHeight).isActive = true** Although the thumbnailImageView is now a rectangle it's now humongous. It looks like it's the size of the the first part of my question. In the cell I only set the height, top, and leading anchors, i left out the width.

Comment: In the snippet you posted about you'd set videoHeight to both height anchor and width anchor. Hope you updated that properly in your code.

Comment: Value for your width anchor should have been self.frame.width / 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213690/discussion-between-subramanian-mariappan-and-lance-samaria).

Comment: You made my day.. +1 for you bro... thanks from Gujarat.